# Morris.js Chart (line) - Is showing a continuous line

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

I am doing maintenance in a system, and I need to change a graph on the dashboard,they are using the morris.js.

I need to create a Morris.Line Graph, but something is not working, and I could not find what I am doing wrong.

The code for now is that:

```
   $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function() {console.log('instagram ') },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                new Morris.Line({
                    element: 'morrisLine1',
                    data: response,
                    xkey: 'y',
                    ykeys: ['a'],
                    labels: ['Daily Progress'],
                    lineColors: ['#f74f75'],
                    lineWidth: 3,
                    ymax: 300000,
                    gridTextSize: 12,
                    hideHover: 'auto',
                    resize: true
                });
            },
            complete: function() { console.log('instagram end')  }
        });
```

Here you will see, in the console, the "response" value:

[image]

But the graph it is showing me that:

[image]

How can I change it to show the waves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that library.
but your response numbers are too similar to show the difference in the chart.
what if you make ymax, ymin dynamic based on min max response?

Comment: Makes sense, I tried it I added the 189700 max and the 189600  to min but is not working, now the line just disappears

Comment: to be honest, you are right; the problem was in the max and the min,  I added the ymax: 'auto',    ymin: 'auto' and it works well... I didn't realize what ymax and ymin work for!